# Query for date groupings?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Client table with basic demographics in rows and a date of birth row (DOB) with a DATE data type.

I'm trying to make a query that will take my entries and count how many clients are between the ages of 18-60, 61-79, 80+.  I'm not sure if I'm having a brain-fart, but I can't figure out how to gather that info from my table...

So what I have is:

```
Last Name   First Name   DOB
Stein      Ethel       1954-01-20
Frank      Sam         1981-05-65
etc...
```

What I want to have is:

```
Ages 18-60
6
Ages 61-79
10
Ages 80+
20
```

Any recommendations to proceed?

Comment: You need to use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function to work out age as of this moment in time. You, then, need to use [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) to group your data based on age

Comment: Welcome to SO. A much better than average first question, all that is really missing is some code (any code) that you have tried yourself. Don't be afraid of looking silly. Although someone people here forget it, most remember that they were newbies once upon a time

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm almost at the end of my first database course, Database Basics.  And it is really just the basics.  This is really helpful info!  Honestly, i regards to my own code, I hadn't been able to get anything remotely close to working.  The best thing I could think up on my own was to convert the DATE data type to an int, and somehow take the current system time and subtract that by a range of 18-60, then have it convert that back to a DATE data type.  But of course that didn't even come close to working lol.

Answer (score 3):

Using @Alex's suggestion

```
declare @today datetime
set @today =getdate()


select 
 s as [start],
 e as [end], 
count(1) as [count]
from Client join
(values (0,17),(18,60),(61,79),(80,9999)) as ranges(s,e)
  on datediff(yy,dob,@today) between s and e
-- where buildingid=1
group by s,e
```

<kbd>**[See demo here](http://rextester.com/ZVBC90371)**</kbd>

Comment: Amazing!  I would have never figured this out, but it is very helpful to see this along with Alex's explanation.  I can't wait to learn more about SQL so I can figure more of this out on my own!  Thanks again for the help!!!

Comment: Where would I add a WHERE clause to this?  Just curious if down the road this could be modified to break this code down per building?  In my building table, I have 4 building codes (1,2,3,4) that each correspond to a particular apartment complex where the tenants live in.  I'm wondering how hard it would be to add a WHERE BuildingCode=1?  I tried adding the WHERE statement at the end of the GROUP BY and it threw an error that I the incorrect syntax.

Comment: @adam the `where` will come right before group by clause